# Querying dynamodb date field with given specific date

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I have records on dynamodb and we're storing created_at field as string on table, in my case i want to get records 1 weeks ago from current time how should I do in golang?

```
oneWeekAgo := time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -7).Unix()
params := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
    FilterExpression: aws.String("#createdAt >= :weekAgo"),
    ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]string{
        "#createdAt": *aws.String("created_at"),
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        ":weekAgo": {
            N: aws.String(fmt.Sprintf("%d", oneWeekAgo)),
        },
    },
}


filterCondition := db.NewCondition()
filterCondition.Add("created_at", params)
```

Comment: When you use `query` in DynamoDB, you must provide a `partition key`. You do not do that in your query

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Scan`, unless you know the exact partition key:

```
    svc := dynamodb.New(sess)

    iso8601Day := time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -7).Format("2006-01-02")

    input := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        TableName: aws.String("YourTableName"), // Replace with your table name
        FilterExpression: aws.String("createdAt > :date"),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            ":date": {
                S: aws.String(iso8601Day),
            },
        },
    }

    result, err := svc.Scan(input)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, item := range result.Items {
        attributeValues, err := dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(item)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(attributeValues)
    }
```

Comment: My problem is i want to query the db with created_at field and  i want to get exactly 1 week before created records then i want to push some events through kafka  1 week passed since they're created, problem is i have so many old records and i dont want to send events for them, after my implementation i want to send events that records exactly created 1 week before, and i am  storing date in format "2023-02-07T14:49:01.686178424Z"

Comment: That's the code I shared, you will be returned data created with in the past 7 days. It's not clear what more you require?

Comment: i've tried your implementation and im getting this error:

Cannot use 'map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{ ":date": { S: aws.String(iso8601Day), }, }' (type map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue) as the type map[string]types.AttributeValue

Comment: Im guessing that happens in the print statement? Try the updated code

Comment: Actually not, ExpressionAttributeValues accepts  map[string]AttributeValue{}
and there is no field such S: on it, so i tried to implement like this:

 
  ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
   ":date": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: val"}

do you think this works?

Answer (score 0):

You must dereference the pointer please try

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        ":date": {
            S: aws.String(iso8601Day),
        },
    },
```